# MSVC Compiler Error C4315 - No Documentation Found

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

When compiling my app today, I encountered this warning (the code, I think, is irrelevant):

> warning C4315: 'MyClass' : 'this' pointer for member 'MyClass::my_data_' may not be aligned 8 as expected by the constructor

I am not able to find any documentation about this warning, in either the online help, my locally-installed help, or via a google search.  I did find one link on a MS forum:

[No documentation for compiler warning C431](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/474052/no-documentation-for-compiler-warning-c4315)5

But no information about the error itself.

Do you have any information about this error?  I'm trying to fogure out how to fix it.

Comment: Error -> Warning? Are you compiling with `-Wall`?

Comment: I have the "treat all warnings as errors" option set.  Nonetheless, I'll edit my post.

Comment: Are you building with /Wp64?  This looks like a possible Win64 portability warning.  C4312/C4313 (close at hand) are /Wp64 only.

Comment: @Steve:  No, I'm compiling in x64 and not detecting 64-bit compatibility issues.

Comment: I can't find anything abot the error but not surprised that it's x64-related given the ref to 'aligned 8'.  Any reason you can think of for the relevant `this` pointer to be screwy? Do you have custom packing on the class(es) involved?

Comment: Except this one.  The code *is* relevant.

Comment: there is custom packing on some classes, but not this one.  some of our classes are packet to 1-byte.

Comment: @Hans:  its going to be niegh impossible for me to post the code.  but i can try

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd look for something (buried in a header?) changing the structure packing from the default.

The warning seems to be saying that whatever type `MyClass::my_data_` is expects to be 8-byte aligned, but it's not being placed at that alignment inside `MyClass`.

Search for `#pragma pack(some-number)` directives that aren't reset with a `#pragma pack()`.

Using `#pragma pack(show)` would probably be helpful, too.

Comment: yep thatsd what i'm looking for